# What is the role of & after gedit?

Tags: gedit

Whenever I want to open a editor from the terminal i write

```
gedit filename.sh
```

But in this case i cannot write again in the terminal until and unless I close the editor first.

But whenever I use the command

```
gedit filename.sh &
```

It returns a value, like this

[image]

and i get my control back over the terminal without closing the editor. I learnt this trick from an youtube video but that guy didnt mentioned why this occurs and what is the number that is being returned. I am a newbie in linux, so this question may be silly to some pros, but still its my doubt and I will be highly obliged if you kindly help me in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run command in background:

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 17227
```

Take a look at output of `jobs`:

```
$ jobs -l
[1]  + 17227 running    sleep 1000
```

You're getting:

- `[1]` job number
- `17227` process id PID

Both ids can be useful in different scenarios. e.g.

Send job to foreground:

```
$ fg 1
```

Send job to background:

```
$ bg 1
```

Kill job:

```
$ kill %1
```

Find out command line of process:

```
$ ps aux | grep 17227
user      17227   0.0  0.0  4268156    500 s002  TN    3:35PM   0:00.00 sleep 1000
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I forgot to say "Thanks.. :) "

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing by executing something like `gedit filename.sh &` is telling your shell to run gedit in the background as a job (as seen by `[1] 3842`).

Comment: ok..so if i create another file like this it will be 2 right? let me try

Comment: But what is the number that is returned?

Comment: The number in the bracket is the job number assigend by your shell followed by the PID (in this case of gedit)

Comment: Okay..Thank u.. :)